# Clear or delete data in Class data container on android

Tags: android, pojo

I would like to clear data inside class data container after my apps sign out,
the order of the process is :

**Signout > Clear data inside ContactItem > intent to register activity**

So when login with different account that class will filled with new data. 
ContactItem will used to store data from API.

Here when call API to get data :

```
private void oauthToken(String msisdn){
    Call<APIResponse<ContactItem>> call = ServicesFactory.getService(this).register(msisdn,getSerialSIM);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<APIResponse<ContactItem>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<APIResponse<ContactItem>> call, Response<APIResponse<ContactItem>> response) {

            if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body().isSuccessful()){
                ContactItem item = response.body().data;
                SessionManager.saveProfile(RegisterPhoneActivity.this, item);
                ContactDBManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).insertContact(item);

            }
            else{
                toast("Authentication failed");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<APIResponse<ContactItem>> call, Throwable t) {
            toast("Authentication failed");
        }
    });
}
```

here is my class data container :

```
public class ContactItem implements Parcelable {
public String caller_id;
public String msisdn;
public String name;
public String status_caller;
public String video_caller;
public String status;
public String created_date;
public String email;
public String caller_pic;
public String serialsim;
public ProfileItem profiles = new ProfileItem();
public ContactItem(){}
public String getName(){
    return name.isEmpty()?"":name;
}

public String getName(String def){
    return name.isEmpty()?def:name;
}

public String getEmail(){
    return email==null?"":email;
}

public String getStatusCaller(){
    return TextUtils.isEmpty(status_caller)?"'No status'":"'"+status_caller+"'";
}

protected ContactItem(Parcel in) {
    caller_id = in.readString();
    msisdn = in.readString();
    name = in.readString();
    status_caller = in.readString();
    video_caller = in.readString();
    status = in.readString();
    created_date = in.readString();
    email = in.readString();
    caller_pic = in.readString();
    serialsim = in.readString();
    profiles = (ProfileItem) in.readValue(ProfileItem.class.getClassLoader());
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(caller_id);
    dest.writeString(msisdn);
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(status_caller);
    dest.writeString(video_caller);
    dest.writeString(status);
    dest.writeString(created_date);
    dest.writeString(email);
    dest.writeString(caller_pic);
    dest.writeString(serialsim);
    dest.writeValue(profiles);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Parcelable.Creator<ContactItem> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ContactItem>() {
    @Override
    public ContactItem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ContactItem(in);
    }

    @Override
    public ContactItem[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ContactItem[size];
    }
};
}
```

and here is where i would to do clear data :

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    String serial = AppPreference.getPreference(MainActivity.this,AppPreference.SERIAL_SIM);
    if (serialSIM == null || !serialSIM.equals(serial)){
        firebaseAuth.signOut();

       //======== Here is ==========

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RegisterPhoneActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: on signout you  can remove data from your shared preference,

Comment: you just want to clear all data inside this class? like re-istantiate it without datas?

Comment: sorry, please check updated above..

Comment: If I am right, you want to clear the 'ContactItem' object you are creating inside the response of outhToken api ?

Comment: @Rai_Gaurav yess correct, how i could to do that?

Comment: I think there is no need to clear 'ContactItem', because it is created everytime you get response from outhToken api.

Comment: whats the point in clearing it?

Comment: i would like to make validation sim card, if user insert different sim card then app will signout and ask user to register, but after user register with new sim card in profile page still showing data from before, that data in ContactItem class..